# How can I get PHP data from Azuracast API json output?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I tried very hard to make output of Azuracast json query, but I cant, I'm a php guy and I don't quite get it. Tutorials didn't work either.

I got my token and eveyrthing. I just want to output a album name, song title and artist to string. That's it. I just want to make my little custom player, which is going well except for this. Can you guys check my code and help me out? I know this questions was already answered, but it didnt help for me. It always outputs nothing on my website.

my api link: [here](https://91.237.70.40/api/nowplaying/2.json)

```
//$url = "https://91.247.70.40/api/nowplaying/2.json";
//$data = file_get_contents($url);
//$infos = json_decode($data, true);
//$nazwa = $infos->cache;
//echo $nazwa;
 function jwt_request($token, $post) {
   $ch = curl_init('https://91.247.70.40/api/nowplaying/2');
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   $post = json_encode($post);
   $authorization = "Authorization: Bearer ".$token;
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   return json_decode($result, true);
}
echo $result->cache;
```

you can see i tried two ways. None worked. I've hidden the token. It is set up correctly, i know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be having multiple problems here. The first one is that your API is served on HTTPS but with an invalid certificate / self signed one. `file_get_contents` and `curl` will by default fail requests to pages with an untrusted cert. First you should setup a Let's Encrypt certificate as shown in the [documentation](https://www.azuracast.com/docker_sh.html#set-up-letsencrypt).

Then your first code will correctly return the decoded JSON data. But you should remove the `.json` at the end of the URL since this is not a file you are requesting but an API route. There you try to access the decoded data as if it is an object but `json_decode($data, true)` returns an assoc array so you need to access the data like this `$infos['cache']`. If you want to get the album name, song title and artist from the data you need to access these fields: `$infos['now_playing']['song']['album']`, `$infos['now_playing']['song']['title']` and `$infos['now_playing']['song']['artist']`.

Your second code example will not work after you fixed the certificate error because the `/api/nowplaying/{station_id}` route is a GET route but you define the CURL request as a POST request.